# Oracle APEX - Breadcrumb entry with multiple parents

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I am working on this app where many pages (8+) are linking to the same page. Every page needs to show correct breadcrumb. Since many pages are linking to the same page, the target page (p5) has a number of breadcrumbs and each breadcrumb has a condition that an application item needs to have a specific value for the parent page.

For example pages 1,2,3,4,6,7 link to page 5. So page 5 has 6 separate breadcrumbs on it where the condition is `when parent_page = x` where x is the parent page number. So if the user comes from page 1, a correct breadcrumb is selected.

I feel that this is excessive and creates a mess. Also the number of pages that link to page 5 seems to grow. I could create new breadcrumbs for each parent page but I feel that this is wrong and want to find a better way. Can anyone point me in the right direction? how have you handled something like this in the past?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done it, but I remember wanting to at one time.  I think you would need to "roll your own" breadcrumbs.  You could use an APEX collection to keep track of the user's navigation by "pushing" and "popping" pages on to and off of the APEX collection.  Then create a SQL-based list region to display these.  You may need to create a bespoke list template to make this list look like breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar requirement. Many paths to a single location and keeping the breadcrumbs in sync with the users path was a coding horror story. Finally we decided on not going down that road. The breadcrumb now shows the main path back to the main screen, which might not be the exact path the user followed. So, just a single breadcrumb per page. If you want to go back to the previous page then a "back" or "cancel" button could still do that, but not the breadcrumb.